# HTML frame / iframe

Tags: html, iframe, frame

I see that HTML has both a `frame` tag and an `iframe` tag. How are they different, and when should one be preferred over the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between IFrame and Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079128/whats-the-difference-between-iframe-and-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How are they different?

A [frame](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#edef-FRAME) appears inside a [frameset](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#edef-FRAMESET). An [iframe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#edef-IFRAME) appears inside an HTML document that has a `<body>`.

> and when should one be preferred over the other?

They do significantly different things.

Both can break linking/bookmarking (so should be used rarely), but the use cases for regular frames make it more likely that will happen with them than with iframes.